# In SQL, how to get two different string values to do an aggregate function?

Tags: mysql, sql

Write a query to get the click-through rate per app in 2019. The schema of the events table is **app_id** (integer), **event_id** (string: "impression", "click", and **timestamp** (datetime). My query is below, but not sure how to filter by impression or click to calculate the click-through rate.

```
SELECT app_id, COUNT(event_id = ‘click’ ) / COUNT (event_id = ‘impression’) as click_through_rate
FROM events 
WHERE  EXTRACT(YEAR from timestamp) = 2019
GROUP BY app_id
ORDER BY click_through_rate DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want `sum()`:

```
SELECT app_id, 
       SUM(event_id = ‘click’ ) / SUM(event_id = ‘impression’) as click_through_rate
FROM events 
WHERE  EXTRACT(YEAR from timestamp) = 2019
GROUP BY app_id
ORDER BY click_through_rate DESC;
```

`COUNT()` counts the number of non-`NULL` values for the expression.  You want the sum where the expression is `true` -- hence `SUM()` instead of `COUNT()`.

Comment: ok makes sense, but is that the correct syntax for getting the values click and impression?

Comment: @EmilyKuo . . . That should count up the rows with those values in MySQL.